# How to get custom log entries into installation.log file?

Tags: install4j

I wrote my first custom screnn yesterday and now I need some informations be looged. I took a look in the api but didn't found any class which looks like a logger class. Is there the possibility to log custom informations to the installation.log file or is it required to create a separatly log file with log4j?

Kind regards
Hardie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call one of

```
Util.logInfo(null, "My message");
Util.logError(null, "My error");
```

Or, if you have caucht a Throwable t

```
Util.log(t);
```

The class `Util` is in the `com.install4.api` package and is automatically imported in all scripts.

Comment: That's it. Now all of my required loggings are listet in the standard installation.log. Thank you very much.